# Exception Occurs in STM32 Reset Handler using VSCode GDB

Tags: gdb, stm32, vscode-debugger, cortex-m

I'm attempting to debug firmware in Vscode using GDB from the STM32CubeCLT toolset. The Vector Table has been relocated to 0x8008200. Using the STM32CubeIDE, I have no problem debugging the software once I set the location of the Vector Table in the debug options. However, if I attempt to debug the software using Vscode it immediately crashes after setting the stack pointer.

[Debugger Halt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbLVL.png)

[Launch Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbBTi.png)

I've verified that _estack is in the correct location (0x20050000), the pc is starting in the Reset_Handler (0x8012030, 0x8012031 in the ELF) and the code is compiled using Thumb instructions.

Does GDB need to be informed that the Vector Table has been relocated similar to changing the debug options in STM32CubeIDE? What am I missing here?

Comment: I assume you are using the Microsoft C++ extension to debug? Does the same issue happen if using GDB outside of VS Code? Please also show you VS Code launch config

Comment: Yes, I am using the Microsoft C++ extension. I edited the original post to include the launch config. I can try using GDB outside of VS Code.

Comment: [ask], [mre], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11107541